# How to Check All Users against UserGroup

Tags: users, query

How can i check if ANY users exist in a particular User Group? I know how to check the current user but not ALL users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got it all sorted:

```
{% if craft.users.group('myusergroup').total() > 0 %}
```